# Flutter Secure Storage -Retrieving Cart data : type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' in type cast

Tags: flutter, dart

I am storing cart data in Flutter Secure Storage and retrieving when app is being loaded. It works fine when cart has multiple items and convert the data into a List. The data comes as:

```
['Instance of Cart', 'Instance of Cart','Instance of Cart']
```

But it shows error when it has single item and it comes as Map and it show the error

```
{"id":1091,"title":"Spanish Olive 340 gm Fragata","imageUrl":"https://api.theshoply.net/images/product_feature_images/spanish-olive-340-gm-fragata_2021_07_12_03_19_08_60ec090cb8143.jpg","price":170.0,"quantity":1}


Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' in type cast
```

Here's the code:

```
String? cartSave = await storage.read(key: CART_KEY);
  if (cartSave != null && cartSave.isNotEmpty) {
    var listCart = json.decode(cartSave) as List<dynamic>;

    var listCartParsed =
        listCart.map((model) => Cart.fromJson(model)).toList();

    if (listCartParsed.length > 0) {
      context.read(cartListProvider).state = listCartParsed;
      print(listCartParsed);
    }
  }
```

This is the code for adding items to cart:

```
final cartListProvider = StateNotifierProvider((ref) => CartList([]));

class CartList extends StateNotifier<List<Cart>> {
  CartList(List<Cart> state) : super([]);

  void add(Cart cart) {
    state = [...state, cart];
  }

  void edit(Cart cart, int quantity) {
    state = [
      for (final cartItem in state)
        if (cartItem.id == cart.id)
          Cart(
            id: cart.id,
            title: cart.title,
            imageUrl: cart.imageUrl,
            price: cart.price,
            quantity: cartItem.quantity! > 0
                ? cartItem.quantity! + quantity
                : cartItem.quantity,
          )
        else
          cartItem,
    ];
  }
}
```

This the the code for storing cart items into secure storage:

```
static addToCart(BuildContext context, int? id, String? title,
  String? imageUrl, double? price, int quantity) async {
Cart cartItem = new Cart(
  id: id,
  title: title,
  imageUrl: imageUrl,
  price: price,
  quantity: quantity,
);

if (isExistInCart(context.read(cartInstance), cartItem)) {
  context.read(cartListProvider).edit(cartItem, 1);
} else {
  context.read(cartListProvider).add(cartItem);
}
var string = json.encode(context.read(cartInstance));
await storage.write(key: CART_KEY, value: string);
}
```

Comment: Can you share the part where you add a single cart to the storage?

Comment: I have updated the post with code. please check now